# How to stub STDIN.noecho(&:gets) in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a method `auth` and I'd like to stub STDIN.

```
def auth
  ...
  @pass = STDIN.noecho(&:gets).chomp
  ...
end
```

I've tried `STDIN.stub(:noecho).and_yield('some_pass')`, and received `NoMethodError: private method 'gets' called for "some_pass":String`. I'm sure there's something missing here but I just couldn't figure out what it is.

Comment: You can use send to get around the private restriction.  But You might reconsider testing STDIN.  It is built in and likely well tested.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. What I was trying to do was to *stub* STDIN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `noecho` method turns off echo and then yields the stream itself, but you're stubbing it to yield a string instead of the io instance. As a result `gets` is called on 'some_pass' which obviously doesn't work

You could do

```
STDIN.stub(:noecho).and_return('some_pass')
```

Or

```
STDIN.stub(:gets).and_return('some_pass')
```

Both should result in `STDIN.noecho(&:gets)` returning the desired string.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to really yield `'some_pass'` to the block? Or do you just want to stub the return value?

I believe you just want to get the return value. Try to use `and_return` or the short hand method for stubbing by passing a hash:

```
def auth
  STDIN.noecho(&:gets).chomp
end

describe "Stubbing STDIN" do

  it do
    STDIN.stub(noecho: "some_pass")

    expect(auth).to eq "some_pass"
  end

end
```